# Muted all contacts somehow in the Samsung messages, I've literally tried every common sense solution

Tags: samsung, contacts, motorola-droid

I've looked up countless forums and message boards and everyone seriously gives the common sense easy answers. There are three

1. To the right of the contact blah blah blah.
2. Power settings on the way the phone manages individual apps blah blah blah.
3. Did you check if the sound is on.
   I'm pretty good when it comes to tech related issues and I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: Have you got sound in other apps ?  The volume control can sometimes allow individual control of sound for a particular app.

Comment: I do have sound across the board in all other apps. I actually finally found the answer. Instead of any settings based options, or battery options I went to messages held down my finger on one and it checked it. Upper left option to select all messages. There is an option on the bottom to mute all. I unchecked it and it worked.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!